# ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Am using Hyperledger latest version 1.4 to build my network following this tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html
and whenever I try to run this command:

`peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem`

i get the following error

```
ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" does not exist
```

any help would be greatly appreciated